# How can I add buttons at the end of each table row?

Tags: javascript, html, button, html-table

I'm trying to insert a button in the end of each row of the table `receitas` but the buttons are being set at the start of the table instead of the end of each row.

```js
function mostraTabelaTeste(aTipo, aLista) {
    tb = '<table>';
    tb += '<tr><th>Tipo</th><th>Nome</th><th>Tempo</th><th>Custo</th><th>Dificuldade</th></tr>';
    for(let i in receitas) {
        if(receitas[i].tipo==aTipo) {
            tb += '<tr><td>' + receitas[i].tipo + '</td><td>' + receitas[i].nome + '</td><td> '+ receitas[i].tempo + '</td><td>' + receitas[i].custo + '</td><td>' + receitas[i].dificuldade + '</td></td><input type="button" id="remove_' + i + '" value="x"</td></tr>';
        }
    }
    tb += '<table>';
    document.getElementById(aLista).innerHTML = tb;
}
```

The line where I put all the properties into the table row (inside of for), I have an input which should be set at the end of the row but instead, it is going to the top of the table.

[image]

Comment: input tag not closed `<input type="button" id="remove_' + i + '" value="x"</td>`

Comment: close the table tag too. tb += '</table>'; in the last

Comment: yep, that was the problem and the   "'</td></td>" was closing td instead of opening... Too many hours in front of pc
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a type error in the cell wrapping the button you're creating `</td>`  instead of starting `<td>`

see belown snippet :

```js
receitas = [
  {tipo:"typ1",nome:"nome1",tempo:"tempo1",custo:"custo1",dificuldade:"dificuldade1"},
  {tipo:"typ2",nome:"nome2",tempo:"tempo2",custo:"custo2",dificuldade:"dificuldade2"},
  {tipo:"typ1",nome:"nome3",tempo:"tempo3",custo:"custo3",dificuldade:"dificuldade3"},
  {tipo:"typ1",nome:"nome4",tempo:"tempo4",custo:"custo4",dificuldade:"dificuldade4"},
]

function mostraTabelaTeste(aTipo, aLista) {
  tb = '<table>';
  tb += '<tr><th>Tipo</th><th>Nome</th><th>Tempo</th><th>Custo</th><th>Dificuldade</th></tr>';
  for (let i in receitas) {
    if (receitas[i].tipo == aTipo) {
      tb += '<tr><td>' + receitas[i].tipo + '</td><td>' + receitas[i].nome + '</td><td> ' + receitas[i].tempo + '</td><td>' + receitas[i].custo + '</td><td>' + receitas[i].dificuldade + '</td><td><input type="button" id="remove_' + i + '" value="x"</td></tr>';

    }
  }
  tb += '<table>';
  document.getElementById(aLista).innerHTML = tb;
}

mostraTabelaTeste("typ1","table");
```

```html
<div id="table"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add one more th for button column in first row. Like below:

```
tb += '<tr><th>Tipo</th><th>Nome</th><th>Tempo</th><th>Custo</th><th>Dificuldade</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>';
```